# GWT - Finding which button is checked in a Dynamically generated list of Radiobuttons

Tags: gwt

I have a for loop that displays a list of text fields and radio buttons.
What is the best way to reference the widgets so that I can read the text fields and aslo find which radio button is checked.
Here is my loop

```java
    for(int x = 0; x<getLoopCount(); x++)
    {
        answerTable.setWidget(x,0, new Label("Answer:"));
        answerTable.setWidget(x,1, new TextBox());
        answerTable.setWidget(x,2, new RadioButton(""));
    }
```

Is there a way to ID each widget so I can reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend grouping the three widgets together in a composite widget like this:

```java
class AnswerComposite extends Composite {
    private final Label label;
    private final TextBox textBox;
    private final RadioButton radioButton;

    public AnswerComposite() {
        label = new Label("Answer:");
        textBox = new TextBox();
        radioButton = new RadioButton("answerGroup");

        HorizontalPanel contentPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        contentPanel.add(label);
        contentPanel.add(textBox);
        contentPanel.add(radioButton);

        initWidget(contentPanel);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textBox.getValue();
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return radioButton.getValue();
    }
}
```

You can then add them to a panel and/or put them in a list like this:

```java
VerticalPanel answersPanel = new VerticalPanel();
List<AnswerComposite> answerComposites = new ArrayList<AnswerComposite>();

for (int i = 0; i < getLoopCount(); i++) {
    AnswerComposite answerComposite = new AnswerComposite();
    answersPanel.add(answerComposite);
    answerComposites.add(answersComposite);
}
```

Checking your widgets then becomes very easy:

```java
answerComposites.get(i).getText();
answerComposites.get(i).isSelected();
```

It will probably also be convenient to add a `ValueChangeHandler` to your `RadioButton`s (see enrybo's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ValueChangeHandler` to your `RadioButton` when you are creating them.

```java
for(int x = 0; x<getLoopCount(); x++){

    answerTable.setWidget(x,0, new Label("Answer:"));
    answerTable.setWidget(x,1, new TextBox());

    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton("");
    rb.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler(){
        @Override
        void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event){
            // Do something
        }
    });

    answerTable.setWidget(x,2, rb);

}
```

The `ValueChangeEvent` will only be fired when the `RadioButton` is checked. It will not fire if another `RadioButton` in the same group is checked.

Since you're adding the `ValueChangeHandler` as you're creating your `RadioButton` you should know what is to be done with it without having to create an ID for it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an adhoc answer, so don't care about the syntax but the algorithmic idea.

1. Extend GWT button.

```java
    abstract class MyButton
    extends Button{
      // provide the appropriate constructor in impl class,
      // especially if using uibinder

      abstract public void helloDolly(... args ...);
    }
```

1. Instantiate all those buttons using MyButton.

   ```java
   MyButton[] buttons = {
     new MyButton(){
        public void helloDolly(... args ...){
          Window.alert("allo allo #1");
        }
     },

     new MyButton(){
        public void helloDolly(... args ...){
          Window.alert("allo allo #2");
        }
     },

     // blah blah black sheep ....
   }
   ```
2. Use clickEvent.getSource() when defining handler.

   ```java
   buttons[i].addEventHandler(
     new ClickHandler(ClickEvent click){
       Object src = click.getSource();
       if (src !instanceOf MyButton){
          throw new MyAngryException("For goodness' sake, pls use MyButton");
          // or ignore
          return;
       }

       ((MyButton)src).helloDolly(... args ...);
     }
   )
   ```